# R: How do I loop over variables with similar names?

Tags: r, nested-loops

I have four dataforms (New_Aud1 through 4) with two columns, and a 5th (Ctrla) with one column which has some overlap with the second column of the others.

The code below finds the last item in Ctrla which matches with anything in column 2 of New_Aud1 and return the position of that item in New_Aud1. It then puts a 1 next to every item at or above that position, and a 0 next to every item below it.

```
x <- 0
Match_Pos <- -1
while(Match_Pos == -1)
{
  last <- Ctrla[length(Ctrla) - x]
  Match_Pos <- match(last, New_Aud1[,2], nomatch=-1)
  x <- x+1
}

New_Aud1$control <- 0
for (i in 1:Match_Pos) {New_Aud1$control[i] <- 1}
```

i.e.

```
New_Aud1       Ctrla
A  B           C
0  5           5
3  7           6           
2  8           7
5  9           10
```

Adds c(1,1,0,0) to New_Aud1, since the last item in C that matches anything in B is 7, which is in the 2nd row of B.

Everything above works the way I want it to.

My question is, is there a way to turn this into a nested loop, where the outer one loops this code over the other three New_Auds, or should I just copy this code 3 times (preferably not, because we may be adding more New_Auds)?

Comment: Can you provide two example dataframes to better describe what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Just did...hopefully that helps you understand what I'm looking for!